# Return a specific word in a string of multiple words in java

Tags: java, string, random, int, return

```
public class test{

     //my words
        private static String[] words = {"apple", "banana", "cat", "dog", "elf", "frog" };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       int randomWord = (int) (Random() * words.length);

        System.out.println(randomWord);

    }//end string   
}//end class
```

I just start a project and all i want to know is how to return a specific word while still having it be random. At the moment it just prints/returns the number of the position in the string. For example i want it to return "cat" and if it does the print "*" for every letter in cat. I already have the code to print the "*" for every letter i just need to get the word back instead of an int.

Comment: Do you know how to access an element in an array?

Comment: `System.out.println(words[randomWord]);`

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate [`Random`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html):

```
Random random = new Random();
```

Use it to get a random number*:

```
int randomNumber = random.nextInt(words.length);
```

Print index of said random number:

```
System.out.println(words[randomNumber]);
```

*<sub>Note that normally you use something like `random.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min` but because your `min` is `0` and because of 0-based array indexes, you can just use `words.length` in this example</sub>